# Facebook Manager Request to claim a page not showing up

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I request to access a Facebook Page it states:

"Your Business Manager Already has an active request on this Page. You'll see a notification if the request is accepted."

But then when I go to my Business page to view the requests it doesn't show up.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: I have this same problem. Been waiting weeks to see *some* kind of prompt on the Page or my own user profile. I'm scrubbing through all inboxs, settings in various Facebook apps and can't find anything.